# Facing error while making a request method using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

TypeScript v4.1.3 Node.js v10.23.1
Error :

```
No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(options: string | RequestOptions | URL, callback?: ((res: IncomingMessage) => void) | undefined): ClientRequest', gave the following error. Argument of type '{ method: string; headers: { 'User-Agent': string; Authorization: string; }; resp: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(res: IncomingMessage) => void'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'method' does not exist in type '(res: IncomingMessage) => void'. Overload 2 of 2, '(url: string | URL, options: RequestOptions, callback?: ((res: IncomingMessage) => void) | undefined): ClientRequest', gave the following error.
```

Code :

```js
import { request } from 'https';
import { version } from '../package.json';
import Error from './ErrorHandler';
import { baseURL } from './Constants';
import Client from '../structures/Client';

export default class RequestHandler {
  public constructor(public readonly client: Client) {};

  public get(endPoint: string, { query, header = {} }: { query: Record<string, string>; header?: Record<string, string> }): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._makeRequest("GET", endPoint, { query, header })
      .then(data => resolve(data.body.message))
      .catch(reject);
    });
  }

  private _makeRequest(requestType: string, endPoint: string , { query, header = {} }: { query: Record<string, string>; header?: Record<string, string> }): Promise<{ statusCode: number, body: any }> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const req = request(
        `${baseURL}/${endPoint}?${this.encodeSearchComponent(query)}`, {
        method: requestType,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': `Node-Weeby HTTP Handler (version: ${version})`,
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.client.apiKey}`,
          ...header
        }, respone => {
          let rawData: string;
          resp.on('data' chunk => {
            rawData += chunk;
          })
          .on('end', () => {
            const res = {
              statusCode: response.statusCode!,
              body: JSON.parse(rawData)
            };

            if(!(res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)) {
              reject(new Error(res.body.message, res.statusCode))
            } else {
              resolve(res);
            }
          })
          .on('error', reject);
        });
        req.end();
      });
    };
  };

  private encodeSearchComponent(queries: Record<string, string>): string {
    return Object.entries(queries)
    .filter(x => Boolean(x[1]))
    .map(x => `${x[0]}=${encodeURIComponent(x[1])}`)
    .join("&");
    }
}
```

I don't know where I did wrong and if you guys have any suggestions for improving my code pls tell me cause I just started working on typescript so I don't have any idea what professionals recommend

It would be a great help thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0):

One of the valid request method overloaded call is:

```
request(URL, OPTIONS, CALLBACK);
```

The error in your code seems to be the Callback part being merged with options because you forgot to close } for the options and went on to write callback inside options. So, typescript received only two parameters which it tried to resolve by checking the other overload containing 2 parameters:

```
request(URL | OPTIONS, CALLBACK)
```

URL is okay but CALLBACK received an object {...} containing the options and the callback, whereas it was only expecting a callback. Hence, the error.

Try this format:

```
request("URL", { }, (response) => { });
// 1st parameter: URL
// 2nd parameter: Options
// 3rd parameter: callback
```

In your code:

```
{
    method: requestType,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': `Node-Weeby HTTP Handler (version: ${version})`,
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.client.apiKey}`,
      ...header
    },
} // You forgot to add this and instead wrote the callback inside
```